# Where do we have to specify the alchemyapi key in the java sdk?

Tags: java, sdk, api-key, alchemyapi

I am using alchemyapi java sdk for my project.I have successfully build the project in the eclipse. But when i am trying to run individual classes than it will showing error for the api key. I have the key what i don't know where exactly this key to be specified in code. i have specified in some places but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried looking at any relevant documentation?

Comment: yes i have checked but unable to understand where to specify.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant documentation can be found [here](http://www.alchemyapi.com/developers/getting-started-guide/twitter-sentiment-analysis)

You need to configure your credentials.py file, where the values need to be changed are: 
    twitter_consumer_key='YOUR_TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY'
    twitter_consumer_secret='YOUR_TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET'
    alchemy_apikey='YOUR_ALCHEMY_API_KEY'

Best of luck!